# How to auto insert a template code into a new file of particular extension, that is created in a particular directory?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a project directory at `~/project`. Under this project directory there are many sub-directories too. What i tried to do is, whenever i create a c++ file (which implies files with extensions .cc,.cpp,.h etc) in a particular directory, auto insert certain code templates into that file.

The template is of the given form :

```
/* 
 * Author :  Name
 * Date   :  Sat Jan 19 12:42:56 IST 2019 (:r!date)
*/
```

Usually the date would be the date of creation of that file, which can be inserted using `:r!date`.

The idea i have come up with so far is creating a `template.vim` file, with the following contents :

```
call setline(1, '/*')
call setline(2, 'Author : ')
" the line below is a blunder. but i hope you get the gist of what im trying.
call setline(3, 'Date : '+ execute "normal! :r!date")
call setline(4, '*/')
```

then till sourcing the template file on creating a new c++ file, like so:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cc,*.cpp,*.h source ~/.vim/ftplugin/template.vim
```

How can i efficiently add conditions for checking creation of a file in my **~/project** directory or any of its sub-directories, with the extension of a c++ file and insert the above template with the specific date and format? Also how to insert this only on creation of a new file rather than an existing file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: There are template plugins, you should search the net for "vim template plugin". Perhaps you find something useful.

If you want to do it yourself:

Create your template file like this (I assume `~/tmpl/tmpl.cpp` as name):

```
/* 
 * Author :  <<name>>
 * Date   :  <<date>>
 */
```

and in your vimrc:

```
function AddTemplate(tmpl_file)
    exe "0read " . a:tmpl_file
    let substDict = {}
    let substDict["name"] = $USER
    let substDict["date"] = strftime("%Y %b %d %X")
    exe '%s/<<\([^>]*\)>>/\=substDict[submatch(1)]/g'
    set nomodified
    normal G
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile *.c,*.cc,*.cpp,*.h call AddTemplate("~/tmpl/tmpl.cpp")
```

The `set nomodified` tells Vim that the file was not modified. That way you can exit the file with `:q` as long as you don't add additional text. Usefull if you typed the wrong file name.

If you only want to act on files within a special directory `~/project`, you can add the following at the start of the function `AddTemplate`:

```
let fully_qualified_file = expand('%:p')
if 0 != match(fully_qualified_file, $HOME . '/project/.*')
    return
endif
```

Comment: did you just repeat back all that i had typed in my post? :D I had clearly mentioned that i have figured out the part of creating a template file and adding it to an autcmd.

Comment: It's okay. Can happen with anyone. By the way you made remember to include 0 with the read command. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: Updated, now easy replace of name, date and whatever you want to add.

Comment: It should work. But would you be able to give me an idea on how to run the autocmd only when creating the new file under a particular directory, like say ~/project, or any of its sub-directories?